# Class name does not name a type c++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to overload the `<< operator` in this class, but the compiler gives me `Pila` is not a type error (`Pila` would be stack, the name of the class). `GetNElem` is another function that I did not include, don't worry.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
class Pila {
 private:
  vector <T> elem;

 public:
  /* Pila(){

  } */

  Pila ( int n ) {
    elem.resize(n);
  }

  void print(ostream & f_out){
    for (int i = 0; i < getNElem(); i++)
      f_out << elem[i] << " ";
    return;
  }


};

ostream& operator << (ostream& f_out, Pila p ){
  p.print(f_out);
  return f_out;
}
```

Comment: `ostream& operator << (ostream& f_out, Pila p )` -- The second parameter, once you get that fixed, should be a const reference, i.e. `const Pila<T>& p`, not `Pila p`.  You are incurring an unnecessary copy when you pass by value.

Comment: The compiler is right: `Pila` is not the name of a class. It's the name of a **template**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Pila` is a class template, you need to specify template argument when use it. And you can make `operator<<` a function template, then

```
template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& f_out, Pila<T> p ){
  p.print(f_out);
  return f_out;
}
```

BTW: It would be better to pass `p` by reference to avoid copy operation on `Pila` which constains a `std::vector`, and make `print` a `const` member function.

```
template <class T>
class Pila {
  ...

  void print(ostream & f_out) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < getNElem; i++)
      f_out << elem[i] << " ";
  }

};

template <typename T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& f_out, const Pila<T>& p ){
  p.print(f_out);
  return f_out;
}
```

Comment: Side note: I would omit the `return` at the bottom of `print`. It doesn't do anything.